# UnauthorizedError: Format is Authorization: Bearer [token] - Vue 3 and Apollo Server, Express, jsonwebtoken, express-jwt

Tags: express, jwt, vuejs3, apollo-server, vue-apollo

I have a Vue 3 app and an Apollo & Express Server.
When I want to communicate with the backend, I encounter those issues (check below):

Backend Error showed by Morgan on the terminal:

```
UnauthorizedError: Format is Authorization: Bearer [token]
    at middleware (/Users/user/vscode/gestion-subvention-api/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:73:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/vscode/gestion-subvention-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/user/vscode/gestion-subvention-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/user/vscode/gestion-subvention-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/user/vscode/gestion-subvention-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/user/vscode/gestion-subvention-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at cors (/Users/user/vscode/gestion-subvention-api/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
    at /Users/user/vscode/gestion-subvention-api/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
    at originCallback (/Users/user/vscode/gestion-subvention-api/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)
    at /Users/user/vscode/gestion-subvention-api/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
```

Frontend error showed by Google Chrome:

```
createHttpLink.js?a012:93 POST http://localhost:4000/graphql 401 (Unauthorized)
eval @ createHttpLink.js?a012:93
Subscription @ Observable.js?a7b2:197
subscribe @ Observable.js?a7b2:279
complete @ Concast.js?5549:57
Concast.start @ Concast.js?5549:83
Concast @ Concast.js?5549:75
QueryManager.getObservableFromLink @ QueryManager.js?cb44:487
eval @ QueryManager.js?cb44:85
eval @ QueryManager.js?cb44:82
step @ tslib.es6.js?9ab4:100
eval @ tslib.es6.js?9ab4:81
eval @ tslib.es6.js?9ab4:74
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.js?9ab4:70
QueryManager.mutate @ QueryManager.js?cb44:47
ApolloClient.mutate @ ApolloClient.js?365c:139
eval @ useMutation.js?89f9:96
step @ useMutation.js?89f9:43
eval @ useMutation.js?89f9:24
eval @ useMutation.js?89f9:18
__awaiter @ useMutation.js?89f9:14
mutate @ useMutation.js?89f9:66
eval @ Login.vue?5326:83
eval @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:1147
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:333
index.js?3ca0:26 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at new ApolloError (index.js?3ca0:26)
    at Object.error (QueryManager.js?cb44:127)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js?a7b2:140)
    at onNotify (Observable.js?a7b2:179)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (Observable.js?a7b2:240)
    at eval (iteration.js?fceb:4)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at iterateObserversSafely (iteration.js?fceb:4)
    at Object.error (Concast.js?5549:36)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js?a7b2:140)
```

the `Vue 3` App main.ts code is:

```
import { createApp, h, provide } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "@/assets/css/tailwind.css";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  from,
  HttpLink,
} from "@apollo/client/core";
import { ApolloClients } from "@vue/apollo-composable";

const my_token = localStorage.getItem("gest_sub_token");

const additiveLink = from([
  new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    operation.setContext(({ headers }: { headers: any }) => ({
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: my_token ? `Bearer ${my_token}` : null,
      },
    }));
    return forward(operation);
  }),
  new HttpLink({ uri: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL }),
]);

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: additiveLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    provide(ApolloClients, {
      default: apolloClient,
    });
  },
  render: () => h(App),
});

app.use(store).use(router).mount("#app");
```

The Apollo server app.ts code is:

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import { join } from 'path';

import { typeDefs, resolvers } from './graphql';
import { JWT_CREDENTIALS, URL, IN_PROD } from './config/env-config';
import morgan from 'morgan';

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, './uploads')));

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(JWT_CREDENTIALS);

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: IN_PROD,
  context: ({ req }) => {
    const user = req.user || null;
    return { user };
  },
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server ready at ${URL}${server.graphqlPath}`);
});
```

the JWT_Credentials is:

```
const JWT_CREDENTIALS = jwt({
  secret: privateKey,
  algorithms: ['HS256'],
  credentialsRequired: false,
});
```

I am getting 401 Unauthorized but when I am using GraphQL playground it's working fine. I don't know if the issue is located on the server side or the client side.

Someone can help me handle this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was simple to solve. It was due to the value assigned to my_token after checking his value inside the localStorage:

```
authorization: my_token ? `Bearer ${my_token}` : null,
```

The right way to solve it is to assign an empty string ``` `` ``` or `""`